# Spring Interceptor which matches user id with a token

Tags: java, spring, security, interceptor

I am porting a REST web application from struts 2 to spring 5 (w/ spring boot). In our Api, we pass three attributes in each request (names are anonymised):

`uuid, token, bananaId`

In the backend we look for a user in a database with `uuid`, and check if it has `token` in it's list of tokens. If it has, the request is authorized and we add `bananaId` to the user's set of bananas.

I can do checking in each request individually -- and this is how it was implemented in struts. How to make a spring interceptor which would do this for each request (excluding a login action)?

I have successfully configured `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`, but I'm stuck on what to do next. Which approach is the best in this case?

EDIT: pseudo code of a controller

```
@RequestMapping("/getFoo")
public GetFooRsponse getFoo(@RequestBody Request request) {
    Optional<User> user = getUser(request.getUuid());
    if (user.isPresent() && user.get().getGcmTokens().contains(request.getGcmToken())){
        user.get().getBanIds().add(request.getbanId());
        // handle request
    } else {
        // unauthorized?
    }
}
```

A solution which would be fine:

```
@RequestMapping("/getFoo")
@CheckGcmToken
public GetFooRsponse getFoo(@RequestBody UserRequest request) {
    // handle request
}
```

Comment: If setting `bananaId` is NOT part of your business login - I will advise you to use Spring Filters. Here is the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html)

But If setting `bananaId` IS a part of business logic - I will advise you to use filters to authorize requests and use interceptor to setup `bananaId` logic.

Comment: I have edited the question. I hope it explain the logic. bananaId is a deviceUuid and the REST application is a backend for a mobile application and each request is expected to have a deviceUuid.

Comment: About interceptor. The signature is:

`public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {`

How can I get my data model (eg. "FooRequst" object) from this? modelAndView is passed in postHandle and I want to have a collection of deviceUuids up-to-date while handling a request.

Comment: You can read your request from `HttpServletRequest getInputStream` method and just convert it to your FooRequest.

Comment: OK but... really...?

Comment: PreHandle means that you request is not handled with spring yet, so it doesn't have to provide you already mapped business entities. 
I prefer to user Jacksons `ObjectMapper` and pass the stream to it and return the necessary object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164159/discussion-between-lutoslaw-and-bogdan-oros).